# Facing issue with using Gemfire cache using PCF Tanzu Gemfire service Springboot microservice

Tags: spring-boot, gemfire

I am working on Springboot REST microservice. Facing issue while doing clear region on partition region type. How to configure Gemfire cache so that my client should be able to add region to server while startup. Also I am thinking of exposing an API to evict cache explicitly. Is there a way we can do it? We had Redis cache implemented now but we want to switch to gemfire as it offers nice GUI to track regions and data using PULSE.
Questions:

1. Gemfire client configuration to add region on startup to be used across microservice.
2. How to evict explicitly. Thinking of an API.

Code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCacheDefinedRegions
public class CloudcachePizzaStoreApplication
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem(s) (as noted in [GEODE-788](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-788), [GEODE-7665](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-7665), [GEODE-7666](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-7666), [GEODE-7670](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-7670), [GEODE-7672](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-7672) and [GEODE-7676](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-7676)) is, is that GemFire/Geode does not support `Region.clear()` for `PARTITION` *Regions* (yet).

When you declare the [`@CacheEvent(allEntries = true)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheEvict.html#allEntries--) annotation/attribute on your managed application component, for example...

```java
@Component
class MyCacheableSpringManagedApplicationComponent {

  @CacheEvict(allEntries = true)
  void nukeAndPave() {
      repository.deleteAll();
      // ...
  }
}
```

This in effect calls `Region.clear()` (see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/2.4.0-M2/spring-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/cache/GemfireCache.java#L95)). This behavior works for `REPLICATE` and `LOCAL` *Regions*, however not for `PARTITION` *Regions*, given the numerous GemFire/Geode problems. It is currently a WIP, though.

There was (partly, still is) an intention in Spring Data for Apache Geode & VMware Tanzu (Pivotal) GemFire to handle cache clear operations.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGEODE-265

However, this is on hold until the above GEODE JIRA tickets get sorted out.